# Как убрать фото у категорий в woocommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно сделать так, чтобы у категорий были только названия + стилизовать под свою тему. У стандартных категорий есть фото. Как убрать это фото?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail', 10 );
```

Comment: Сработало, благодарю! Вы не знаете, как убрать число товаров в категории, которое рядом с названием?

Comment: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', '__return_false' );`